# How do I insert Chinese characters into a SQLExpress text field?

Tags: character-encoding, full-text-search, sql-server-express, cjk

How do I insert Chinese characters into a SQLExpress text field? I'm using SQL Express from VS 2008. When I add Chinese characters, either via an import app I wrote or by pasting them in from the data view inside Visual Studio, they end up as question marks.

Answer (score 18):

Just add an 'N' before your text delimiter in the INSERT/UPDATE statement for fields of the nchar/nvarchar/ntext type:

INSERT INTO myTable (myField1, myField2) VALUES (N'any chinese character',N'any arabic character')

Answer (score 5):

Be sure you made your column type nchar, nvarchar or ntext.  So you can store Unicode.  It is all rather well described [here...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa223981.aspx)