# How to insert and display Chinese character in oracle database?

Tags: sql, oracle

i have inserted Chinese character into oracle database. but the value is not suitable with the character, the value such as Â¿Â¿ :Â¿Â¿Â¿!. the data type is varchar2. same problem when i want to display the data. How to store and display Chinese character into oracle 10g database ?

Comment: What is the database character set (`select * from v$nls_parameters`)?  What is the client `NLS_LANG`?  What is the client code page?  What application are you using to insert the data?  What application are you using to view the data?

Comment: Kindly visit this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303178/how-do-i-insert-chinese-characters-into-a-sqlexpress-text-field) it might help.

Comment: Provide us the character sets of the database and the client (application, terminal, etc. ...) you use to insert data. One of them might have less characters than another.

Answer (score 0):

To support unicode character use driver **Properties** as shown :-

```
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.52.45.36:1521:ORCL";
            Properties connectionProps = new Properties();           
            connectionProps.put("useUnicode","true");             //Property 1
            connectionProps.put("characterEncoding","UTF-8" );    //Property 2
            connectionProps.put("user", "SYSTEM"); 
            connectionProps.put("password", "Root-123");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,connectionProps);
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
```

And ensure that the datatype in the oracle table is **NVARCHAR/NCHAR**. Also, while inserting use function such as **TO_NCHAR('-some-unicode-value-') or N'-some-unicode-value-'**

This should be it!

Comment: Did this help you?