# Insert objects into database

Tags: node.js, sql-server, datetimeoffset, nvarchar

I have ten thousand records in the postObj object and need to insert into a SQL Server database.

The object structure :

```
{
  postObj : [
     {
      start_coordinates":  {
                    "latitude": 1.373211,
                    "longitude": 103.955124
    },
    "end_coordinates": {
                 "latitude": 1.31974,
                    "longitude": 103.889633
    },
      longitude: 114.063042,
      latitude: 22.366266,
      event_name : '社交聚會'
      event_country: 'New Yotk',
      event_date: '2021-06-15 00:02:18-15',

    },
 {......
  }
]
```

SQL Server database table structure:

```
event_name , nvarchar(500)
event_country, nvarchar(500)
event_date, datetimeoffset(7)
start_coordinates_latitude, varchar(100)
start_coordinates_longitude, varchar(100)
end_coordinates_latitude, varchar(100)
end_coordinates_longitude, varchar(100)
```

insert js code

```
        sql.connect(dbConfig, err => {
        const request =  new sql.Request();
    
        let cols = [];
        let inputs = [];
        for (let k in postObj) {
            request.input(k, postObj[k]);
            cols.push(k);
            inputs.push('@' + k);
        }
     
        let query = `insert into test (${cols.toString()}) values (${inputs.toString()})`;
    
        request.query(query, (err, result) => {

              console.log(err);
            //stuff here
        });
```

I have following issue:

1. filed [event_date] cause the error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

2. filed [event_name ] , do I need to put the "N" (like  SET @something = N'sometext') for Chinese characters, if need, how to do it?
3. how to split  the sub-object  of start_coordinates into  start_coordinates_latitude and start_coordinates_longitude?

Thanks for the help

Comment: '2021-06-15 00:02:18-15' - this is not a date, what's with the "-15" at the end? i would probably use an openjson call and put the whole thing into that, should be quicker than doing one by one

Answer (score 0):

Here are the possible causes for each problem:

1. Event date is causing the error because the MSSQL doesn't support the time format
   you are trying to insert. Check this post for available time formats is MSSQL

[Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string while inserting datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119133/conversion-failed-when-converting-date-and-or-time-from-character-string-while-i)

2. The solution for the event name as you said is to use the N in order to work for different languages. Check some examples here

[How do I insert Chinese characters into a SQLExpress text field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303178/how-do-i-insert-chinese-characters-into-a-sqlexpress-text-field)

3. The easiest way you can split the start_coordinates is by looping through each object in you array and creating the start_coordinates_latitude and the start_coordinates_longtitude as follows

This will create the 2 new properties

```
object.start_coordinates_latitude = start_coordinates.latitude;
object.start_coordinates_longitude = start_cordinates.longitude;
```

Delete the old property start_coordinates

```
delete object.start_coordinates;
```

Comment: for Item 1, I update the object value directly , object.event_date = obj.event_date + ":00"

Thanks .